# Bash script- number of processes sorted

Tags: linux, bash, syntax

im trying to improve my bash on my road to become a DevOps,
one of my excercises states that i should be able to

**1-Write a bash script using Vim editor that checks all the processes running for the current user**

**2-Extend the previous script to ask for a user input for sorting the processes output either by memory or CPU consumption, and print the sorted list.**

**3-Extend the previous script to ask additionally for user input about how many processes to print. Hint: use head program to limit the number of outputs.**

The error message is a syntax error, it doesnt seem to work, any ideas or tips ?

```
#!/bin/bash
 
read -p "Press 1- to sort by memory OR 2 to sort by CPU consumption" sorting
read -p "how much output should be displayed, choose a number between 1-9 ?" output
 
if[$sorting = 1];
    ps auck-%mem | head -n $output | grep kami
else
    ps auck-%cpu | head -n $output | grep kami
fi
```

Cheers
Kami

Comment: Check your script with http://shellcheck.net

Comment: You need spaces: `if [ $sorting = 1 ];`